# How to encrypt form data sent to oauth server?

Tags: java, oauth

I see that authentication data is being set as part of Form Data in the oauth request sent to the server.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsrD7.png)

Is there a way in which this can be hidden in the network tab? Thanks

Comment: You probably want to transmit a salted and hashed password rather than a password in the clear.

Comment: Please also post your code that generated this.

Comment: If you use OAuth to authenticate the request, the `Authorization` header shouldn't have `Basic xxxx` in it, but `Bearer xxxx`.